# Fulls stops in a title are not searchable in SOLR

Tags: java, search, solr, punctuation

I have a fairly straight forward SOLR search implementation using DataImportHandler.
One of the fields is the name of a business.  It creates a searchable field with Business Name as part of it as well as description.

The issue is that a search for a company called C.E.D. will not find it.  I know it is there.  A more general search does return a result.

Funny enough there is also a company called CED in the index.  Searching C.E.D. does not return that company but searching CED does.  However, searching CED does not return the company C.E.D.

As a write this I realise that what I probably need to do is change the business name field so it is consumed as is and no Filters mess with the actual combination of words or punctuation?

Comment: please provide the details for your field type ? what anaylsis you perform at index and query time ?

Comment: Field type is text_general but I dont think that matters? What I need to know is what field type and what to do (analysis) to it to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal configuration with WhitespaceTokenizerFactory can work for you.
This will create tokens on white space and lower case the text and would match the indexed terms.
C.E.D would match C.E.D and c.e.d

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>    
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

If you want `C.E.D, c.e.d or ced` to match `C.E.D or c.e.d or ced`, you would need to check [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) filter

Comment: Yes.  I came across WordDelimiterFilter factory this morning I will try it and see if that is the answer. Certainly looks like it.